# combobox default value

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net application, and I have a combobox which should contains a display member (text) and a value member (integer).

the problem is:
I want to set a default value to that combobox when the form load but I don't have a load event as I create the form and the combobox dynamically. i have used the combobox.selectedvalue =6 but it doesn't work.

note: I can't use the selectedindex property because sometimes the value comes from a DB table primary key which is not the same as the combobox index.

the code:

```
Private Sub fill_combo(ByRef combo As ComboBox, ByVal nodes As HashMap)
    Dim comboData = New BindingList(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))

    nodes.movefirst()
    Do While Not nodes.eof
      If check_atrbValue(nodes.key, nodes.value, "string", "other") Then
        comboData.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String)(nodes.key, nodes.value))
      End If
      nodes.movenext()
    Loop
    combo.DataSource = comboData
    combo.ValueMember = "Key"
    combo.DisplayMember = "Value"
    combo.selectedvalue=6
End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to already have that in your code: `combo.selectedvalue=2`, though the actual case should be: `combo.SelectedValue=2`.

Comment: i did not understand your comment.

Comment: comment from oded is about lowercase/uppercase : S elected V alue  vs  s elected v alue.

Answer (score 0):

you do have a loaded event, even if you created the UIElement dynamically. But since you created it this way, you should also hook the event handler in code behind :

```
   AddHandler mycombobox.Loaded, Sub(sender As System.Object,
                       e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) _
                                    CType(sender, ComboBox).SelectedIndex = 2
```

But maybe you will want too hook to another event, like one stating that data is loaded from your DB...

```
  AddHandler ??.DataAvailable, Sub(???) SelectionComboBox.SelectedIndex = 2
```

where SelectionComboBox is a member of your class that you initialize / add with code behind. and DataAvailable is your event. It might be like :

```
    Public Event DataAvailable(ByVal DefaultValue As Integer)
```

and so you can use that value in the event handler. ( just an idea) :=).

Don't forget to remove handlers if you add/remove several times the ComboBox (to avoid memory leaks)